# Long insert query

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, node.js, wamp

I want to insert about 12500 lines into my database for a map for a game server.
this is my script generates the query

```
sql = "INSERT INTO `legends`.`map` (`x`, `y`, `land`, `collision`, `impedance`, `effect`) VALUES "
for (y=0;y<ig.game.collisionMap.data.length;y++){
   for (x=0;x<ig.game.collisionMap.data[y].length;x++){
      if (x==0&&y==0){
         comma=""
      }else{
         comma=","
      }
      sql=sql+comma+"("+x*55+","+y*55+",'kesmai',"+ig.game.collisionMap.data[y][x]+","+ig.game.backgroundMaps[0].data[y][x]+", '0')";
   }
}
console.log(sql)
```

The output is y=86 x=145
My client side script has access to the data for the maps so I was just pasting the output to phpMyAdmin to run the query.  The problem I hit (which I expected) was my php script can only run 30 seconds this is my error.

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.4.10.1\libraries\session.inc.php on line 92

I am running a WAMP server and I tried to edit my php.ini file here

```
; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time = 0

; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data. It's a good
; idea to limit this time on productions servers in order to eliminate unexpectedly
; long running scripts. 
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to -1 for the CLI SAPI
; Default Value: -1 (Unlimited)
; Development Value: 60 (60 seconds)
; Production Value: 60 (60 seconds)
; http://php.net/max-input-time
max_input_time = -1
```

no luck so far... Any suggestions on how to run a long query such as this>?

I was considering temporarily putting it in my server script which runs in node.js

Comment: If you read the error message, it looks like phpmyadmin is setting a different execution time in `C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.4.10.1\libraries\session.inc.php`.  Try editing that file or the phpmyadmin configuration instead of php.ini

Comment: You can just group your data into chunks of 100 and run a separate insert for each.

Comment: `set_time_limit(0);` at the top of the PHP script - but really you should pass the data to PHP (in eg JSON) and use a prepared statement.  The next problem you will hit i'm fairly certain is that MySQL will not accept a query of that size and/or PHP will run out of memory trying to deal with a string that large.

Comment: grouping in chunks of 100 would be a paint to keep track of because I'd have to do it 120 times.  Also the script isn't php as written its plugged into phpMyAdmin but I cuold insert it into php if I have to.

Comment: Can you explain your architecture more? Your example code is in JS and the question is tagged Node.js, but you are talking about a PHP specific problem and PHPMyAdmin? Are you just using Node to construct a statement and copy/pasting it into PMA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You guys have some really great sugguestions that I wasn't able to get to work for my specific application.  My solution was to execute the query from node.js sending the sql from my client to the server.  Rather  than using phpMyAdmin.  I did try removing the time limit from my phpMyadmin script but it didn't work.  I passed the query via websockets but it isn't required.

Comment: In addition I should say that max_execution_time = 0 isn't working as you're expecting. So if you need, just set it to some long value instead, say to 300 (seconds).

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for is `set_time_limit()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

But you should see if there's any way to improve the performance of the query itself.

Comment: it isn't a php script unless phpMyadmin allows you to insert php but as far as I know it isn't a php script

Comment: @Shawn if it's not a PHP script, why did you tag PHP?